# Issue with hiding the Tabbar when Detailed View is suppose to display with SwiftUI

Tags: listview, navigation, swiftui

I am able to hide the Tabbar successfully but as can be seen in the screen shots I am left with the bottom portion of the detailed view with a grey cut off which will go away when I interact with the screen.

[image]

[image]

I am able to achieve the results above by toggling a bool variable when the detail view is displayed which the code snippet below:

```
.onAppear{
    self.displayDetails.showFullScreen.toggle()
}
```

and when the user hits the back button the toggle is revered and the tabbar is displayed again.

Does anyone know how a can remove the grey area at the bottom of the detailed view when it first appears vs when the user interacts with the screen!?

Update:
In my AppView view, I have the following code:

```
...
var body: some View {

    VStack {

        containedView()

        // **** Hide the Tab Bar ***
        if (!displayDetails.showFullScreen) {

            ZStack(alignment: .top) {

                BottomBar(selected: self.$selected)
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.horizontal, 22)
                    .background(CurvedShape())


                Button(action: {

                }) {

                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 55, height: 55)

                }.background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .offset(y: -25)
                    .shadow(radius: 5)

            }.background(Color("Color").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))

        }

    }

}
```

As you can see, the if clause removes the tabbar and leaves the `containedView()` visible, when use clicks on one of the List items in the List view.

Comment: That depends on how do you hide it, would you show the code reacting on that `showFullScreen.toggle()`

Comment: @Asperi i have added the code that shows the clause to hide the tabbar portion of the view

Comment: Interesting... did you try to remove `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` for color?

Comment: @Asperi It is being 'removed' as it is in the if statement. But I removed the code totally and it still has the same result...

Comment: Then the reason not in the provided code but in `containedView()`

Comment: @Asperi I think the issue is because of timing. That is to say the onAppear function gets called too late and the detail view still has the dimensions of the containedView which accounts for the tabbar. I have tried using `gestures` on the list cells, but it does not work. It does not consistently navigate to the detail view on tap. When it does the view is full screen and no gray area at the bottom. Do you know of a way to navigate to the detail view programmatically and not use NavigationLink ? This way maybe i can use `gestures' and code the navigation push to the detail.